# Error using map function in edgarWebR 1.1.0

Tags: r, dictionary, utf-8

I wrote a script for downloading and analyzing 13F filing from a select number of fund managers using the great package edgarWebR in R. Unfortunately the script stopped working after my update to version 1.1.0 of edgarWebR. I get the following error message whilst running this part of the script:

```
 map(filings_incl_href$href, filing_details)
```

filings_incl_href$href contains the hrefs of all the fund managers 13F-filings, e.g. the first one is: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1540531/000154053121000004/0001540531-21-000004-index.htm

Here's the error message:

> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
> Error in check_result(res) :
> EDGAR request blocked from Undeclared Automated Tool.
> Please visit https://www.sec.gov/developer for best practices.
> See https://mwaldstein.github.io/edgarWebR/index.html#ethical-use--fair-access for your responsibilities
> Consider also setting the environment variable 'EDGARWEBR_USER_AGENT

Not sure what is causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.